# The cursor to selection command doesn't consider the normal direction of the face

Tags: normals, snapping, 3d-cursor

**gif A)** The cursor to selection command doesn't consider the normal orientation of the face.

**gif B)** You can use the Cursor tool with Geometry as the Orientation option to get the normal orientation of the face, but you cannot position it exactly in the center of the face because you position the cursor manually.

Do you know how to improve this problem?

---

**gif A**

[image]

**gif B**

[image]

Comment: worse filling a bug?